# Single most important information resource to keep informed of Microsoft technologies?

Tags: resources

I'm looking for an information resource (RSS preferred) to keep on top of Microsoft's doings. For me, that would include software releases, service packs, MS research projects, APIs, business news, and probably quite a few things I don't even know exists.

Is there anything like that, or do I have to collect the stuff from first principles?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will find one rss to rule them all, so to speak ;), but [Scott Guthrie's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx) will certainly keep you on the pulse of things happening at MS, given that he is actively involved in a lot of M$'s projects and naturally knows, and blogs about many other MS products.

IMHO ScottGu's Blog is essential reading for any developer.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found trouble locating one such resource. I get most of my info (fast enough I would say) by following the RSS from the Developer Evangelists here in Sweden. They are usually rather quick in communicating relevant news.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently managing the same issue with Google Reader, aggregating various developer and team blogs from all over the company. I also keep up with some CodePlex projects that seem to be relevant to the future technology strategy of the company.

MSDN is also good, but not always up to date.

Comment: Would you mind posting your list of feeds?